# Каким лучше всего образом передать POST или GET запрос в Python?

Tags: python, http, requests, https

Мне нужно передать запрос, в Telegram документации говорится чтобы сделать какой-либо запрос используйте пример `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/<method>`, но насколько безопасно передавать такие запросы, ведь если открыть вкладку Network в разделе разработчика(F12) то можно увидеть что токен в открытом виде, и боюсь что если отправлять запрос просто через пайтон используя библиотеку `requests` то через сниффер узнать токен тоже не проблема.

Как отправить безопасно запрос?
(Так-же мне надо передать POST запрос через Google API(конкретно что за библиотека смысла говорить нету, так как мне нужно зашифровать как-то запрос, или скрыть от глаз людей)

Comment: API Телеграма использует https протокол - данные шифруются. Даже если кто-то и перехватит трафик, то он не сможет узнать токен от вашего бота.

Comment: А с Google API та же история?

Answer (score 0):

конечно же, все сущности, которые относятся к авторизации или аутентификации должны передавать в теле запроса `POST`.

Не имеет значения какую библиотеку или какой язык вы будете использовать. Имеет значение только как организована авторизация.

Не работаю с ботами телеграма, не могу сказать почему токен передается в ссылке.

А вот протокол действительно должен быть `https`, это решает львиную долю проблем.

Comment: "токен указанный в параметре запроса ссылки является публичным". Не в коем случае. Благодаря токену можно делать с ботом все что угодно. Он не в коем случае не должен быть рассекречен. Об этом [сказано](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#botfather) в документации.

Comment: @Никита Я и говорю беглый взгляд и не опытность в этом деле